# is there any way to display .rem file in ImageView

Tags: android, image

I am unable to display .rem image file in my `ImageView`. How can I convert a `.rem` file into a `.jpg` file in Android programmatically? or Is there anyway to display .rem file in android. I can open that file in gimp tool. but unable to display in imageview in android

Answer (score 0):

If I trust what I found on Google, .rem files are Blackberry encrypted files. The REM file can be decrypted only by password used in the BB smart phone or by the same password in the Blackberry Desktop Software. (cf http://www.downloadatoz.com/file-extensions/rem-file-extension.html)

It seems to be difficult to convert it on an Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

The .rem file is a BlackBerry encrypted file.

If it was properly copied off the BlackBerry using the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) you can remove the extension .rem and rename it .jpg.

Since the Blackberry uses a master key encryption, if it was not properly copied off using the BlackBerry it was encrypted on, it will be extremely challenging to break the encryption.